# Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in Devise when setting up user confirmation

Tags: email, devise, sendgrid, confirmation

When I try to set up user confimation in my Rails app I get the following error.

```
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in Devise::ConfirmationsController#create
535 Authentication failed: Bad username / password
```

I looked in the terminal, and the e-mail is set up and everything, but the e-mail is not getting sent.
s
Not sure what parts of code I need to post, but here's the code from my config/environments/developer file and my setup_mail.file.

Any ideas? I not sure what's going on here.

```
development:

Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false

  config.eager_load = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: 'localhost:3000'}
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
    end

setup_mail

if Rails.env.development?
 ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
 ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
 address:         'smtp.sendgrid.net',
 port:            '587',
 authentication:   :plain,
 user_name:           ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
 password:        ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
 domain:              'heroku.com',
 enable_starttls_auto: true
 }
end
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your environment variables are set properly? Try printing them out somewhere in your application to confirm.

Comment: How do you do that? Sorry, I'm new to Ruby and Rails.

Comment: No worries. Somewhere in your code that you know will be executed, place

puts **********************
puts ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME']
puts ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD']
puts **********************

Comment: I used `heroku config` to make sure that the Sendgrid account info is correct.

Comment: So heroku would use your production environment, not your development environment. Development is if you are testing locally. I think that's the problem.

Comment: What should I use for development?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66278/discussion-between-eddiezane-and-clyde-brown).

Answer (score 0):

Heroku will by default use the rails production environment. You have defined your mailer settings only for the development environment. Moving the configs to `config/environment.rb` or `config/environments/production.rb` should fix your issue.

You can reference https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html#-Configure-ActionMailer-to-Use-SendGrid for more information.